# Azure File "System error 1396 has occurred. The target account name is incorrect."

Tags: azure

I'm testing out deploying out Azure File using AD DS permissions.  I was able to sync our onprem file server to Azure.  I am able to mount/map the drive using "net use \storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net\filesharename STORAGEACCOUNTKEY /user:Azure\storageaccountusername

However when I try to map the drive not using "STORAGEACCOUNTKEY /user:Azure\storageaccountusername" I get the message

System error 1396 has occurred.  The target account name is incorrect

Anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Currently working on the same thing with an Azure AD DS domain and have a ticket opened with Microsoft as it is preventing a move to Windows Virtual Desktops. I'll update with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. For me it was several parts;

- I using a forward lookup zone in my on-premise DNS instead of a conditional forwarder to Azure Private DNS.
- I had the VNet associated with the Storage Accounts Private Endpoint set to a custom DNS server (DC inside the the Azure IaaS). This was the big one as it can't use a custom DNS server.
- I also had to recreate the Private Endpoint to have it pull my changes to the VNets DNS.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be the guide we were using had us create some AD records for the storage account which is no longer the proper method. Removing those records and re-joining the storage account to AD DS corrected the issue.